# How do I customise the last reply timestamp in messages in BuddyPress?

Tags: wordpress, message, buddypress

Currently, the last reply timestamp of `thread_id` in the inbox or sent tab is formatted like this: `August 21, 2017 at 5:06 am`

I am using `bp_message_thread_last_post_date()` to display the timestamp.

How do I change this so it displays the last reply in the format `2 days, 11 hours ago`?

Answer (score 0):

In the buddypress function you are calling, it echos the value from a similarily named function that applies a filter.  You should create your own filter named 'bp_message_thread_last_post_date' to change the format of the date as you wish.

In your functions.php file, add something like the following:

```
add_filter( 'bp_message_thread_last_post_date', 'fluffyKittenDate', 10, 1 );

function fluffyKittenDate($oldformat) {
   // reformat date contained in oldformat here and return the new value
 }
```

Be sure and make the priority of add_filter method high enough to ensure your filter runs last.